# Is it possible to change the superclass variable from a subclass's method and use it in another subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

> ***Edited:*** Dou to @Prune comment I've edited the question

I have a main class as superclass and have many classes extended from it.

I want to change a variable of superclass **from a method inside of** subclass and use it in another subclass.

Assume this:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'GOOGLE'   # This is a variable

    def plus(x, y):
        return x + y


class SubClassOne(MainClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


    def substract(self, x, y):
        return x + y
        self.test = 'YAHOO'    # Here I'm trying to change the 'test'


class SubClassTwo(MainClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def multiply(self, x, y):
        print(self.test)      # Here I'm printing the 'test' and I want to have it with 'YAHOO' value
        return x * y


run = SubClassTwo()
run.multiply(2,5)
```

1- Look at the variable `self.test = 'GOOGLE'` in SuperClass initializing.

2- Then I change it in **SubClassOne.substract()** to `self.test = 'YAHOO'`.

3- I use `self.test` in SubClassTwo to reach the changes from SubClassOne.

Means that if i print it, I wanna `YAHOO` in the output. But the actual output is  `GOOGLE`

What should I do?

Comment: You'd have to have `SubClassTwo` inherit from `SubClassOne`

Comment: This does not address the underlying design problem; you simply re-worded the original implementation characteristics.  What you describe is either a violation of Python semantics, or a process with so much syntactic overhead that it strongly suggests your design does not properly serve your solution needs.  Please edit your question to tell us what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You have a critical flaw in your design assumptions:

> 3- I use self.test in SubClassTwo to reach the changes from SubClassOne.

No, you don't.  SubClassTwo and SubClassOne are sibling subclasses.  `self.test` in SubClassTwo refers to the `test` attribute of a SubClassTwo instance; SubClassOne is not any part of this pedigree.  SubClassTwo inherits *only* from MainClass.  A change to the `test` attribute of a SubClassOne instance *cannot* automatically affect a SubClassTwo instance.

In your comment to the older answer, I see what may be your problem:

> the methodes in runtime are consecutive in order, ClassOne then Class Two

You declared two child **classes**, independent of one another, *not* methods.  `substract()` [sic] and `multiply` are methods of two *different* classes.  For example, were you to try at the end of your posted code,

```
print(run.substract(5, 2))
```

you would get a runtime error: `run` has no method named `substract` -- `run` is of type SubClassTwo, which has no such method.  `substract` is a method of SubClassOne only.

---

Very simply, you need to determine what you want your objects to do, and then write the corresponding Python structures to match.  Since you haven't told us enough about your desired operation, we can't alter your posted code to match.  Simply setting an instance attribute requires only one class, not three.

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent for me. I'll describe my problem more clearly. I'm running an Automation Test using appium chrome driver. Assuming that we have 1 page and 1 modal window and 2 button named btn_A and btn_B. Here, btn_A is out of the modal in the window and ofcourse has a specific (x,y) coordinates. When you click  on the btn_B, the modal page without close button opens. also I'm at the webview context and so btn_A is not clickable, so the only way is to get coordinates of btn_A before clicking on btn_B. This is the main problem. Getting coordinate is inside the second class.

Comment: We need you to edit your question with any critical information, *not* "bury" those details in comments.  Also, if you significantly change the question, then you should post a new question.  If a valid answer to the original question is made *invalid* by your clarification, then you should consider a new question.  This is your judgment call.

Comment: I've edited the question and now it's clear enough to undrestand what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get `YAHOO` as output by `self.test` of the second class , attributes and methods of classes works in that way : B inherits from A , when you create an object , and you try to execute a method or class of that object , it will be searched in the class A first then B , so if its not re-declared in B it will show the A's one , that's what happens in your case , the attribute `self.test` is not re-declared in `SubClassTwo` so its normal that it will show `GOOGLE` as output , you have to redefine it on that sub class also

Comment: Infact I cannot do this, because in real code, assume that self.test is something that should be run from ClassOne, and it cannot define in SuperClass. Also the methodes in runtime are consecutive in order, ClassOne then Class Two

Comment: @adrenalineWest yes that's what i meant , redefine it in ClassTwo

Answer (score 0):

You can make `SubClassTwo` inherit from `SubClassOne` as it will also inherit that overriding behavior:

```
class SubClassTwo(SubClassOne):
    def multiply(self, x, y):
        print(self.test)  # prints "YAHOO"
        return x * y
```

Comment: I cannot inherit SubClasses from each other. They're all should be inherit from a certain SuperClass.

Comment: @adrenalineWest Yes, in this example, both `SubClassTwo` and `SubClassOne` inherit from `MainClass`.